# the whole data are deleted from database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, ios9

I'm developing a note app, as its name indicates it's clear what this app does

The problem is when I press the trash button, the whole data are removed from database, all the notes will be removed once the button is pressed,it works like "delete all" , only the data in the view should be deleted.

How I can solve this problem ?

```
 @IBAction func moveToTrash(sender: AnyObject) {

let text = textView.text

if (text.isEmpty){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning !", message: "There's Nothing to Delete", preferredStyle: .Alert)


    let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
        print(action)
    }
    alertController.addAction(okayAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false) {

    }


}else{

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
    as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
do {
    if let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
        for result in results {
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(result)
        }

        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
    return
}

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}

}
```

note that I'm still newbie in iOS development

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's doing this because that's what your code tells it to do. This code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note",    inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
do {
    if let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
        for result in results {
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(result)
        }

        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
}
```

Fetches every instance of the `Note` entity and then loops through them, deleting each one. Then it saves changes. Poof! No more notes.

Your view controller probably has a property that refers to the currently-displayed note. In your screenshot it would be the object that contained the text "note 2". You need to delete just that object, using `deleteObject`. You don't need to perform a fetch, because you already have the object that you need.